# Adding a subview inside of a UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm writing an app where I need to use a fairly "complex" `UIStoryboardSegue`. The designer gave me the following:

[image]

Now the basic idea behind the segue is simple, sliding up the `source.view`, then sliding up one more view before eventually sliding the `destination.view`. However, my question is the following:

How do I insert a second view in-between the `source.view` and the `destination.view` from a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue` ? Obviously I can't just do `addSubview`, since there is no view to add to. Is there another place to add a view in a `UIStoryboardSegue`, so I can still create this segue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look into the answer posted below and consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer hope it helped :) I found question interesting hence +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is what you want

[image]

You can achieve it very easily,

**Step 1:**

Create a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue` and override `perform`

```
import UIKit

class SpecialEffectSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {

        let firstVCView = self.source.view as UIView!
        let secondVCView = self.destination.view as UIView!
        let intermediateView = UIView()
        intermediateView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        secondVCView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        intermediateView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(intermediateView, aboveSubview: firstVCView!)
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView!, aboveSubview: secondVCView!)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView?.frame = ((firstVCView?.frame)?.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!
            intermediateView.frame = (intermediateView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))
        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                secondVCView?.frame = (secondVCView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!
            }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: {
                    intermediateView.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though code looks huge and complicated what is happening in it is pretty simple.

Get the `source` and `destination` `viewController's` view using

```
    let firstVCView = self.source.view as UIView!
    let secondVCView = self.destination.view as UIView!
```

Because you need a intermediate view which is red in color here you create one more view

```
    let intermediateView = UIView()
    intermediateView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Now get the UIScreen width and heght so that you can configure these views frame so that it looks good as per your need

```
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    intermediateView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
```

Note that the I set the frame of `SecondVC` and `intermediateView` such that they are below screen bounds and Ill animate them to come up in `UIView.animate` block

Now obviously because animations are happening on key window of your app access the key window

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
```

Now insert the subviews to window as per your need.

```
    window?.insertSubview(intermediateView, aboveSubview: firstVCView!)
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView!, aboveSubview: secondVCView!)
```

So after this I have views stacked up as FirstVCView -> IntermediateView -> SecondVCView

Now we have pretty much what we need isnt it. Now animate it using `UIView.animate`

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView?.frame = ((firstVCView?.frame)?.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!
        intermediateView.frame = (intermediateView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))
    }) { (Finished) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            secondVCView?.frame = (secondVCView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!
        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: {
                intermediateView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }
```

Important thing to notice is `intermediateView.removeFromSuperview()` in completion block.

Now I have decided to present destination using `self.source.present(` if you need to push destination VC with your funky animation say

```
self.source.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: false)
```

Thats all :)

Now open your storyboard, drag a segue from one your FirstVC to SecondVC and select the segue class as `SpecialEffectSegue` thats it now enjoy

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I love how you're going like it's *very easy* and then provide a big chunk of code, ha. Won't look all that easy to newbies. Looking sweet, though.

Comment: @linusgeffarth : hehehehe code is huge but very simple one :) hence I said very easy :D

Comment: @linusgeffarth : Thanks a lot for the encouraging comment mate :)